# Is there any way to exclude the last occurence of a character from a regex group with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to write a regex that matches the following lines:

```
int func ( int argument, char* str)
for( int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
if( true )
```

but not thoses ones:

```
int func (int argument char* str)
for(int i = 0; i i < 25; i++)
if(true)
```

In litteral, I want to match lines in which there is any whitespace following an opening parenthesis or any whitespace preceding a closing parenthesis.

I started by writing the following regex:

```
grep -E '[^\(]\( [^ ] \)'
```

But it is not working, since there may be valid spaces between the parenthesis.

My question is: Is there any way to exclude the last occurence of a character from a regex group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In litteral, I want to match lines in which there is any whitespace following an opening parenthesis or any whitespace preceding a closing parenthesis.

You may use this `grep` with an alternation:

```
grep '([[:blank:]]\|[[:blank:]])' file
```

- In default `grep` regex mode (BRE) there is no need to escape `(` and `)`
- `[[:blank:]]` matches a space or a tab character
- You need to escape `|` in BRE